# how to retrieve 0 instead of NULL values when result set is 0 (Counting business days)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I'm counting business days between two dates.  Some of my results legitimately should be NULL, but some are returned as NULL that should instead be 0.  This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_key asc) BusinessDaysID,
  BSDAYS * CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN -1 ELSE 1 END FinaldDateCount
FROM
  DIM_DATE B
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) BSDAYS
    FROM CALENDAR
    WHERE
      BSDAYS >= CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ApprovalDate ELSE B.ClosingDate END
      AND BSDAYS < CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ClosingDate ELSE B.ApprovalDate END
  ) R1
```

Source DIM_DATE B example:

`Date_Key ClosingDate ApprovalDate
38544   2018-01-18  2018-02-05
38545   NULL    NULL
38546   NULL    NULL
38547   NULL    NULL
38548   2018-05-01  2018-05-01
38549   NULL    NULL
38550   NULL    NULL
38551   NULL    NULL
38552   2018-03-08  2018-03-15
38553   NULL    NULL
38554   NULL    2018-04-25
38555   NULL    NULL`

Source Calendar Example:

`BSDAYS
2018-04-27
2018-04-30
2018-05-01
2018-05-02
2018-05-03
2018-05-04
2018-05-07
2018-05-08
2018-05-09
2018-05-10
2018-05-11
2018-05-14
2018-05-15
2018-05-16
2018-05-17
2018-05-18
2018-05-21
2018-05-22
2018-05-23`

This is what I'm getting now:

`BusinessDaysID FinalDateCount
38544   12
38545   NULL
38546   NULL
38547   NULL
38548   NULL
38549   NULL
38550   NULL
38551   NULL
38552   5
38553   NULL
38554   NULL
38555   NULL`

and I would Like to:

`BusinessDaysID FinalDateCount
38544   12
38545   NULL
38546   NULL
38547   NULL
38548   0
38549   NULL
38550   NULL
38551   NULL
38552   5
38553   NULL
38554   NULL
38555   NULL`

If you notice on the Date_Key 38548 is coming as NULL and should be 0.

What's wrong with my query, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [`ISNULL` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: i dont think you guys got the OP's point. He wants NULL when there is no dates to compare. Check the expected output: he is looking for 0 only if the actual difference between two comparable dates is 0.

Comment: B3S- Exactly !!

Comment: B3S You are totally right, because if I try ISNULL(BSDAYS,0) *, everything will come as 0 and I just want 0 when actual difference between two comparable dates is 0.

Comment: `ISNULL` is still the answer here. For example, for `ClosingDate` use `ISNULL(ClosingDate,ApprovalDate)`. If both `ClosingDate` and `ApprovalDate` are both `NULL` then `NULL` will still be returned.

Comment: Your example results don't seem to match your query.  They have a `Date_Key` column, but your query assigns the name `BusinessDaysID` to its first column, and seems to be selecting different data than the Date_Key of DIM_DATE.

Comment: I just fixed the names, thanks this is an alias.

Comment: @JCACERES Guess the reason for the problem is `SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) BSDAYS` - here you assign NULL as soon as the result is 0...

Comment: @JCACERES, this is a side issue, I'm sure, but it is not just a matter of the column alias.  The query you present appears to be selecting *different data* than what you present in your example results.

Comment: @Tyron78  SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) BSDAYS because if I don't do that everything will come as 0, So now I'm trying to fix the null when is supposed to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the NullIF and added a little logic in the top query.

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_key asc) BusinessDaysID,
 CASE
    WHEN B.ApprovalDate=B.ClosingDate THEN 0
    ELSE NULLIF(BSDAYS,0)
 END * CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN -1 ELSE 1 END FinaldDateCount
FROM
  DIM_DATE B
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) BSDAYS
    FROM CALENDAR
    WHERE
      BSDAYS >= CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ApprovalDate ELSE B.ClosingDate END
      AND BSDAYS < CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ClosingDate ELSE B.ApprovalDate END
  ) R1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a somewhat different approach.  The `CROSS APPLY` is a MS-ism, and somewhat difficult for me to reason about.  It doesn't look like it's gaining you much over ordinary subqueries.  This is much easier for me to read, and it should do the job:

```
SELECT
  Date_Key AS BusinessDaysID,
  CASE 
    WHEN B.ApprovalDate <= B.ClosingDate THEN
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Calendar C
       WHERE C.BSDAYS BETWEEN B.ApprovalDate AND B.ClosingDate)
    WHEN B.ApprovalDate > B.ClosingDate THEN
      (SELECT -COUNT(*) FROM Calendar C
       WHERE C.BSDAYS BETWEEN B.ClosingDate AND B.ApprovalDate)
    ELSE
      NULL
  END AS FinalDateCount
FROM
  DIM_DATE B
```

Note that it relies on the fact that when at least one of `B.ClosingDate` and `B.ApprovalDate` is NULL, then neither `B.ApprovalDate <= B.ClosingDate` nor `B.ApprovalDate > B.ClosingDate` evaluates to true.  In those cases, the date count is selected as NULL directly, without a subquery.  Otherwise, the appropriate aggregate (sub)query is performed on the CALENDAR table.

Comment: Is retrieving everything as negative values. (-)

Comment: Not for me, @JCACERES, but following what your original query appears to be doing, it does return negative results when the approval date is later than the closing date.  If that's not what you want then change `-COUNT` to `COUNT` in the second alternative of the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_key asc) BusinessDaysID,
  BSDAYS * CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate = B.ApprovalDate THEN 0
                WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN -1  
                ELSE 1 
            END FinaldDateCount
FROM
  DIM_DATE B
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) BSDAYS
    FROM CALENDAR
    WHERE
      BSDAYS >= CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ApprovalDate ELSE B.ClosingDate END
      AND BSDAYS < CASE WHEN B.ClosingDate > B.ApprovalDate THEN B.ClosingDate ELSE B.ApprovalDate END
  )
```